# jQuery json format

Tags: jquery, json

Why does this won't work?

```
var data = {"one": [
    {"slot1":true, "app":"facebook"},
    {"slot2":true, "app2": "facebook"}
]};

$(data.one).each(function() {
    if(this.slot1==true){
        $('#dropable').find('.1_1').append('<img src="img/apps/' + this.app1 + '.png" alt="' + this.app1 + '">');
    }
    if(this.slot2==true){
        $('#dropable').find('.1_2').append('<img src="img/apps/' + this.app2 + '.png" alt="' + this.app2 + '">');
    }
});
```

my #dropable:

```
<div id="dropable" class="drag"><div class="app 1_1"></div></div>
<div id="dropable" class="drag"><div class="app 1_2"></div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What does it do, what doesn't it do, what should it do?

Comment: out comes:

 <img alt="undefined" src="img/apps/undefined.png">

but it should be display:
<img alt="facebook" src="img/apps/facebook.png">

Comment: `this.app1` is undefined, but it should have still worked, it just would have given you the text `"undefined"` as alt text and the image name which should have been clearly visible with inspect element.

Comment: Also, classes cannot start with a number.

Comment: Please notice that its called `droppable`

Answer (score 2):

You have two DIVs with the same ID.  Try changing '#dropable' to '.drag'.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code.

First `$().each` is for DOM elements, not for your own arrays/objects.  You want `$.each`.  Second, `this.app1` doesn't exist in your object, you have `app` and `app2`.

Lastly, and most importantly, you have 2 IDs of `dropable`.  You can't do that.  IDs are supposed to be unique.  Use a class instead of an ID.

```
<div class="drag"><div class="app 1_1"></div></div>
<div class="drag"><div class="app 1_2"></div></div>
```

And then do it like this:

```
var data = {"one": [
    {"slot1":true, "app1":"facebook"},
    {"slot2":true, "app2":"facebook"}
]};

$.each(data.one,function() {
    if(this.slot1==true){
        $('.drag').find('.1_1').append('<img src="img/apps/' + this.app1 + '.png" alt="' + this.app1 + '">');
    }
    if(this.slot2==true){
        $('.drag').find('.1_2').append('<img src="img/apps/' + this.app2 + '.png" alt="' + this.app2 + '">');
    }
});
```

Comment: thx works perfectly. But I have one more question. Can I count maybe with a for loop the '.1_1' and '.1_2' ... ?

Comment: @Evolutio: You can do `$('.drag').find('.app').each(` to loop over each of the `.app` elements.